# Bootstrap : Usage of breakpoints in some specific cases i.e. col-md-auto justify-content-md-center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Though  effectively using breakpoints but somehow unable to figure out these breakpoint specific cases

1) How `col-md-auto` will work differently than `col-auto` ?

2) How `justify-content-md-center` is different than `justify-content-center` ?

examples can be seen [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bootstrap 4, the `md` breakpoint applies to screen width 768px and wider. So any `-md` CSS classes that are used will **apply the appropriate CSS properties on 768px and wider**, and revert to default behavior at smaller widths.

> "How `col-md-auto` will work differently than `col-auto`?"

- `col-md-auto` is natural width columns on "medium and up" screen
  widths over 768px.
- `col-auto` is natural width columns on all screen widths.

Remember that `*-auto` width columns shrink to fit the width of their content and layout horizontally (row). On screen widths less than 768px, **the `col-md-auto` are going to revert to stacking vertically full width** since that's the default behavior of `<div>`. However, the `col-auto` are going to remain horizontal and shrink-to-fit on *all* screen widths.

> "How `justify-content-md-center` is different than `justify-content-center`?"

- `justify-content-md-center` is flexbox center on "medium and up" screen
  widths over 768px.
- `justify-content-center` is flexbox center on all screen widths.

The default flexbox alignment is "start" (or left aligned with `flex-direction:row`), so the `justify-content-md-center` is only going to apply on md-and-up, and then **revert to the default behavior `justify-content:start` on smaller screens**.

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/tdQYPLOsq4